# Java Awt program problem with BufferedOutputStream

Tags: java, awt

I have made this simple program which opens a frame and in which you can write in the textarea given.You can count the number of words and characters using count button or you could save the text of the textarea to the local file-"trial.txt"

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

class trial extends Frame
{
    static TextArea ta=new TextArea("Welcome");
    static Label l1=new Label("Words:");
    static Label l2=new Label("Characters:");
    static Button b=new Button("Count");
    static Button save=new Button("Save");
    static BufferedOutputStream bos;

    trial()
    {
    //Setting position
    ta.setBounds(300,300,300,300);
    l1.setBounds(50,50,100,100);
    l2.setBounds(50,200,100,100);
    b.setBounds(650,300,50,50);
    save.setBounds(650,400,50,50);

    //Setting up file for saving
    try {
        bos=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("trial.txt"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    save.addActionListener(new Save());

    //Adding the components
    this.add(ta);
    this.add(l1);
    this.add(l2);
    this.add(b);
    this.add(save);

    //adding actionlistener to button
    b.addActionListener(new actionlistener());

    //setting up frame
    this.setSize(1000,1000);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class actionlistener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String text=ta.getText();
            String words[]=text.split("\\s");
            l1.setText("Words:"+words.length);
            l2.setText("Characters:"+text.length());
        }
    }

    public static class Save implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String text=ta.getText();
            byte[] arr=text.getBytes();
            try 
            {
                bos.write(arr);
                bos.flush();  
            } catch (IOException f)
            {
               f.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        trial ttt=new trial();
    }
}
```

But this is not working. The count button is working fine but the save button does not work. I do not understand what the error is. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

*Edit:It is working now.Just moved the location of the txt file to the same as of the location of the java file and it started working.Thanks for your help.

Comment: What problem are you seeing? Do you get an exception? If so, what is the exception? (Post the complete exception stacktrace) In your `Save`, make sure not to swallow any possible exception you might get in your `try-catch`. Because currently, if and `IOException` would occur, you wouldn't see a thing. So _at the very least_ do `f.printStackTrace()`, to see what's happening.

Comment: Also look at [JTextArea#write](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write(java.io.Writer))

Comment: Sidenote: Is there a specific reason for using AWT instead of Swing?

Comment: yeah i am doing a java course and it teaches awt before swing so i have started with awt.

Comment: also i added f.printStackTrace(left it bymistake) and there is no IO error

Comment: You don't close `bos`. You can replace `flush()` with `close()`Watch your [naming](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)
*...and it teaches awt before swing...* while superficially a good idea, it actually isn't. Using awt components is actually a waste of time - they're dinosaurs. The parts of awt you need (e.g. layouts and the second events model) can be learned *through* Swing